# Can an anonymous type be queried using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, anonymous-types

I want to read some lookup data from the database, using EF, so I do the following:

```
    public object LocationLookUps()
    {
        var locationTypes = ClientContext.LocationTypes;
        var serviceCategories = ClientContext.ServiceCategories;
        var serviceTypes = ClientContext.ServiceTypes;
        var timeZones = ClientContext.TimeZones;

        return new {locationTypes, serviceCategories, serviceTypes, timeZones};
    }
```

Later, within my consuming code, I want to query each of these types to check whether a given locationType, timeZone, etc... are valid values. If I had returned a `List<LocationType>`, then I can query it as:

```
var locationType = list.SingleOrDefault(t => t.LocationTypeCode = "B");
```

Can you do the same with the anonymous type?

Comment: It is not generally useful to return new anonymous type instances from methods. The one exception would be a generic method where the caller is using the exact same anonymous type (the compiler will make it the same type if the properties are exactly the same), but that's a very unusual scenario. If you have a need to return new instances of objects from a method, generally you really should just declare a new named type. Why don't you want to do that here? Smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to return an anonymous type from a method, and by returning object, you are discarding design-time knowledge of the type information. There is no way to do what you're asking.

That does not mean that there isn't a way to do what you want, however. Some options:

- return each lookup separately, in four separate methods
- create an
  AllLookups class which includes typed properties for the four lookups
  and return it from the method
- use the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and expose methods for specific lookup-related queries each from their own methods

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. C# is strongly typed. Compiler at compilation time finds all anonymous types and converts them to real types. And all work goes with anonymous types converts to work with this generated real types.

In your code you donn't know a future name of real type. So you can only use

```
var temp = new {something};
```

and then use temp localy or by reflection (dynamic keyword) in different places

You return Object. So other code will interpret it like Object. And you can not make cast, because you don't know a name. I suppose you have to make a some ViewModel class that will contain four your fields